# Setup problem encountered by wrapping a React-Beautiful-DND + React-Window virtual list with AutoSizer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized, react-beautiful-dnd, react-window

When wrapping my virtual list `<FixedSizeList>` component (*react-beautiful-dnd* + *react-window*) with an `<AutoSizer>` component (*react-virtualized-auto-sizer*) I'm receiving the following error:

```
react-beautiful-dnd

A setup problem was encountered.

Invariant failed: provided.innerRef has not been provided with a HTMLElement.
```

The error doesn't occur if I don't wrap the `<FixedSizeList>` component with `<AutoResizer>` and supply hard-coded values instead.

My program implements 2 separate, non-draggable lists that I can drag-and-drop to and from.  Becasue the lists aren't draggable it's not a typical "board", but I used **[React-Beautiful-DND's CodeSandBox for React-Window Basic Board](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-virtual-list-board-vgvzt)** as a guide to make it work just as well.

**List.js**:

```
import { Draggable, Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import { FixedSizeList } from "react-window";
import AutoSizer from "react-virtualized-auto-sizer";
import ListItem from "./ListItem";
import React, { memo, useCallback } from "react";

const List = ({

        ID,
        data
    }) => {

    const listItemRenderer = useCallback(({ data, index, style }) => {

        const item = (data && data[index]);

        if (!item) {

            return null;
        }

        return (

            <Draggable
                key={item.ID}
                draggableId={item.ID}
                index={index}
            >
                {(provided) =>

                    <ListItem
                        data={item}
                        draggableProvided={provided}
                        virtualStyle={style}
                    />
                }
            </Draggable>
        );
    }, []);

    return (

        <Droppable
            droppableId={ID}
            mode={"virtual"}
            renderClone={(provided, snapshot, rubric) => (

                <ListItem
                    data={data[rubric.source.index]}
                    draggableProvided={provided}
                    isDragging={snapshot.isDragging}
                />
            )}
        >
            {(provided, snapshot) => {

                const dataLength = (data)
                    ? data.length
                    : 0;

                const itemCount = (snapshot.isUsingPlaceholder)
                    ? dataLength + 1
                    : dataLength;

                return (

                    <AutoSizer>  //Error here caused by wrapping <FixedSizeList> with <AutoSizer>
                        {({ width, height }) => (

                            <FixedSizeList
                                width={width}   //AutoSizer supplied value
                                height={height} //AutoSizer supplied value
                                itemSize={100}
                                itemCount={itemCount}
                                itemData={data}
                                outerRef={provided.innerRef}
                            >
                                {listItemRenderer}
                            </FixedSizeList>
                        )}
                    </AutoSizer>
                );
            }}
        </Droppable>
    );
};

export default memo(List);
```

**ListItem.js**:

```
import React, { memo } from "react";

const ListItem = ({

        data,
        draggableProvided,
        virtualStyle
    }) => {

    return (

        <div
            {...draggableProvided.draggableProps}
            {...draggableProvided.dragHandleProps}
            ref={draggableProvided.innerRef}
            style={{

                ...draggableProvided.draggableProps.style,
                ...virtualStyle
            }}

        >
            {data.name}
        </div>
    );
};

export default memo(ListItem);
```

Regardless of the error, everything seems to still function as it should, but I'd really like to understand the problem before moving forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dug into the **[AutoSizer](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-auto-sizer)** component to find the answer.

The error was logged because the `children` property of the AutoSizer HOC was not being rendered since the `width` and `height` values were `0`.  This is also why everything still functioned normally, as the `width` and `height` state values were eventually updated, but only after the initial render.

**AutoSizer (index.esm.js):**

```
// Avoid rendering children before the initial measurements have been collected.
// At best this would just be wasting cycles.
var bailoutOnChildren = false;

if (!disableHeight) {
if (height === 0) {
    bailoutOnChildren = true;
}
outerStyle.height = 0;
childParams.height = height;
}

if (!disableWidth) {
if (width === 0) {
    bailoutOnChildren = true;
}
outerStyle.width = 0;
childParams.width = width;
}

return createElement(
'div',
{
    className: className,
    ref: this._setRef,
    style: _extends({}, outerStyle, style) },
!bailoutOnChildren && children(childParams)
);
```

Therefore, the solution is to supply `defaultWidth` and `defaultHeight` **[props](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/AutoSizer.md)** with non-zero value to ensure that the component renders on mount, albeit with non-automated sizes:

```
//...

return (

    <AutoSizer
        defaultWidth={1}
        defaultHeight={1}
    >
        {({ width, height }) => (

            <FixedSizeList
                width={width} 
                height={height}e
                itemSize={100}
                itemCount={itemCount}
                itemData={data}
                outerRef={provided.innerRef}
            >
                {listItemRenderer}
            </FixedSizeList>
        )}
    </AutoSizer>
);
```

Comment: I tested this solution - it fixes the problem. However, I am using it with a VariableSizeList instead of a FixedSizeList, and I notice that introducing a default height and a default width actually messes up the initial height calculation for the first few children elements...still investigating this